# How is phenol antiseptic?

Tags: bacteriology, toxicology

What makes phenol an antiseptic, is it because of its acidity which may increase the proton concentration at cell membrane? I am unable to figure out the exact mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for phenol being antiseptic is it's effect on proteins which it denaturates. It also causes leakage of cellular membranes. See the paper in reference 1 for some details and a load of references. They say in the section on phenol:

> Phenolic-type antimicrobial agents have long been used for their
>   antiseptic, disinfectant, or preservative properties, depending on the
>   compound. It has been known for many years (215) that, although they
>   have often been referred to as “general protoplasmic poisons,” they
>   have membrane-active properties which also contribute to their overall
>   activity (120) (Table ​(Table22).
>
> Phenol induces progressive leakage of intracellular constituents,
>   including the release of K+, the first index of membrane damage (273),
>   and of radioactivity from 14C-labeled E. coli (242, 265). Pulvertaft
>   and Lumb (386) demonstrated that low concentrations of phenols
>   (0.032%, 320 μg/ml) and other (nonphenolic) agents lysed rapidly
>   growing cultures of E. coli, staphylococci, and streptococci and
>   concluded that autolytic enzymes were not involved.

Reference:

1. [Antiseptics and Disinfectants: Activity, Action, and Resistance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC88911/)